# Keep inactive local SVN working copy with minimum footprint

Tags: svn

here is my scenario:I have a root folder that contains a number of files and folders related to a project. The root folder is under version control, but only some of the files/subfolders contained in it are actually added to the repo. This is done because only those files need to be safely tracked and shared with a larger working group

Now, I'm not working on the project anymore and I would like to retain a local copy with the minimum possible footprint. I would also like the copy to still retain all the information to re-connect to the repo, if this makes sense. In practice, I would like to:

1. retain all the files that are not under version control (obviously)
2. retain an .snv folder with the "metadata" about the repo status, but no actual data in it (currently the .svn folder is about the same size as the versioned files, I think because it keeps a local copy of the repo version?)
3. [Optional] be able to remove the versioned files, but able to effortlessly re-download them from the repo should I need to work again on them

(1) is trivial

(3) I think I can do by just deleting them manually (without using SVN to do so), so that at next "update" it will find them as missing and download them again, right?

What about (2)? I found posts of people asking if you can prevent SVN from storing the pristines, and the answer was no. However, that was more intended as a permanent setting while actively working on a project. Here I'm asking if I can delete that data somehow and have SVN download it again if say, in a year I need to start working on the repo again. Can I go in the SVN and download some "data subfolder" without breaking anything? Any other idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You want a [sparse checkout](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.sparsedirs.html), and you want it to be so sparse that there's nothing in it.  In your checkout root directory, run this command:

```
svn update --set-depth empty
```

This will remove all versioned items from your SVN working copy (it leaves unversioned items as well as unversioned files in versioned directories).  This command doesn't necessarily remove all the files from your pristine store, but you can force this with a [cleanup](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svn.c.cleanup.html) in your root directory (assuming your client is version 1.8 or later):

```
svn cleanup
```

From [the changelog](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/CHANGES):

```
Version 1.8.0
(18 Jun 2013, from /branches/1.8.x)
http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/tags/1.8.0

 User-visible changes:
  - Minor new features and improvements (client-side):
    ...
    * 'svn cleanup' now runs SQLite "vacuum" to reclaim space (r1418459)
```